# 'AbortError: The operation was aborted.' - Error when adjusting HTML 5 video.currentTime in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video

When using Firefox and changing the position of a video using HTML5 video. Does anyone have insight to what causes this?

Here are my ideas:

1. Setting it to a time value that has no corresponding frame -  I have attempted to always set it to a time where a frame exists to counter this
2. The video frame does not load by the time the next frame is asked for - in order to test this I have set the timeout to 5 ms, this definitely drops the amount of errors so that is some evidence that this is the source of the error.

I have made slider that adjusts video time that replicates the error:

```js
var vid = $('#v0')[0];
var slider = document.getElementById('vidSlider')
linkVideoToSlider();

vid.onplay = vid.onclick = function() {
  vid.onplay = vid.onclick = null;

  setTimeout(function() {
    vid.pause();
    slider.value = vid.currentTime / vid.duration * 100
    vid.currentTime += (1 / 29.97);

  }, 12000);

  setInterval(function() {
    $('#time').html((vid.currentTime * 29.97).toPrecision(5));
    slider.value = vid.currentTime / vid.duration * slider.max;
  }, 100);
};

function linkVideoToSlider() {
  var adjustVideoTime = function() {
    //Note that we attempt to adjust to a time that has a frame.
    setTimeout(function() {
      vid.currentTime = Number.parseFloat(slider.value / 29.97).toFixed(4);
    }, 5);
  }
  slider.oninput = adjustVideoTime
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Frame number:
<p id="time"></p>
<video id="v0" controls tabindex="0" autobuffer preload>
    <source type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.webm"></source>
    <source type="video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;" src="http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.ogv"></source>
    <source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4"></source>
    <p>Sorry, your browser does not support the &lt;video&gt; element.</p>
</video>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Time of video slider:</p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1024" value="0" class="slider" id="vidSlider">
</div>
```

if you prefer JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tehsurfer/9ahz5rmd/52/

Comment: have you encoded the video with the MOOV atom at the start? My guess is if the metadata hasn't loaded yet you may be hitting an unexpected error

Comment: Thank @Offbeatmammal, I did not know that encoding with a MOOV was a thing to do, I will look into how to do this

Comment: To check this I have tried this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tehsurfer/9ahz5rmd/55/) with the .mp4 version removed. Behavior appears to remain unchanged

Comment: this seems to be FF related only, here is a bug-report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1507193

Comment: Yeah that seems to be pretty solid evidence that it is just a bug. What is the standard practice on SO if a question turns out to be a bug?

Comment: here is an answer on meta on how to proceed if questions turns out to be a bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308817/what-do-i-do-if-a-question-i-asked-turned-out-to-be-a-platform-bug

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a [reported bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1507193) in Firefox, fixed in version 70+.

`AbortError: The operation was aborted`

Is output to console when either:

1. A seek in video element is aborted.
2. The time of a video element is adjusted.

Some developers there say that Firefox performs much slower than Chrome or Edge in these scenarios, but I haven't found a way to validate a difference personally.

I will update this answer if a bug fix or workaround is found.

## Update:

After updating Firefox to 70 it appears to be fixed and performance seems to have improved.

Comment: The bug mentions it is fixed in version `70`

Comment: bug still in 66